# include statement uses in C/C++ IDE

Tags: c

What determines when a file needs to be copied into a c/c++ project, instead of just using a #include statement? And if the IDE has project options that let the user list directories to include, how is that different than using many #includes in the source code? Does it just save lines of code? 
I'm using a derivative of eclipse, which is TI Code Composer Studio.

Answer (score -2):

I think maybe the project options allows you to specify the directory where the included files are to be found, and adds that directory to the search path.